# Can a set be neither open nor closed?

Tags: general-topology

Can a set be neither open nor closed? An example would do. I cant think of any.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $[0,1)$ in the usual topology on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott why not make that an answer?

Comment: @Jason: Can do.

Comment: Now I want to encourage the author to think of sets that are **both** open and closed at the same time.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I know those. $\Bbb R$ for example

Comment: Fun fact: a topology in which every set is either open, closed, or both is called a door space. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Door_space

Comment: @JennieDurham Good!

Comment: Another example is $\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb N\setminus0\}$, the set of integer reciprocals.

Comment: I don't know how far back the door "joke" goes... it found its way into Munkres' classic text, at the least.

Comment: This is answered here as well: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186101/an-example-of-neither-open-nor-closed-set/186102 (Linking the Duplicates Questions and Answers Explicitly)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One very familiar example is the set $[0,1)$ in the usual topology of $\Bbb R$: it’s not open, because it does not contain any nbhd of $0$, and it’s not closed, because $1$ is in its closure.

Comment: Does that mean singletons are neither open nor closed, too? I apologize for following up an old question.

Comment: @Invisible I believe (in the usual topology of $\Bbb R$), singleton sets $\{r\}$ for some $r \in \Bbb R$ are equivalent to closed intervals $[r, r]$, which are closed but not open.

Comment: In particular $\{r\}$ is not open because it does not contain any nbhd of $r$, and it is closed because its complement $(-\infty,r) \cup (r,\infty)$ is open because it's a union of open sets.

Answer (score 16):

Another example: the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology. It's not open, because every interval contains irrationals. It's not closed, because every irrational is a limit of rationals.

Answer (score 6):

As the other answers have already pointed out, it is possible and in fact quite common for a topology to have subsets which are neither open nor closed. More interesting is the question of when it is *not* the case. A [door topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Door_space) is a topology satisfying exactly this condition: every subset is either open or closed (just like a door).

Conversely, we can ask whether subsets can be both open and closed, and this is the more well-known property of [connectedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space): a connected space is one where the only closed-and-open sets (clopen sets) are $\emptyset$ and $X$, which are always clopen in any topology. Thus in a connected door topology, you have $A$ is open iff $A$ is not closed, except for $A=X$ or $A=\emptyset$, where $A$ is both open and closed.

The most common door topology one comes across is the [discrete topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space), where every subset is both open and closed. A nontrivial example of a *connected* door topology is given by the collection of open sets $\scr U\cup\{\emptyset\}$ given any [ultrafilter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter#Formal_definition_for_ultrafilter_on_a_set) $\scr U$.

Answer (score 1):

Any non-empty,  proper subset of a topological space endowed with the indiscrete topology.

Comment: Clarification: "trivial" here meaning *indiscrete*, not *discrete* - arguably both are trivial, although the former is somehow more trivial.