# Is this set "not closed"?

Tags: real-analysis

Is it correct to say that this set $E=(0,1]$ where $E\subseteq R$ (Where $R$ is the set of real numbers) is **not closed?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An example of neither open nor closed set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186101/an-example-of-neither-open-nor-closed-set) (see the highest voted answer)

Comment: Some would say that it's as correct as the claimant's capability to back up said statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Closed sets are the complements of open sets. Therefore we check if the complement of $(0,1]$ is open or not.
$$\mathbb{R}\backslash(0,1]=(-\infty,0] \cup (1,\infty)$$
An open set is a set for all points there exists a neighborhood contained in the set with positive radius. But, for point 0, no matter how little you go to $+$ side, you always go off the set. Therefore $\mathbb{R}\\(0,1]$ is a not open set, and therefore $(0,1]$ is a not closed set.

Comment: Could you explain further why (0,1] is not an open set? What would a similar example be of an open set? Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: @user11015000 So, as in the example above, if a set $E$ includes a boundary point it is not open. By this logic, any purely open set and their unions are open sets. No problem, glad if I could help. (purely open: $(\cdot,\cdot)$) I advise you to check the linked thread as well, the OP there described open sets better than I did.

Comment: and purely closed is [.,.] ?

Comment: @user11015000 Not exactly. For example, $[0,\infty)$ is a closed set. There are sets that are neither open or closed. The confusion is normal, but the main idea is: Open sets and closed sets are not opposite definitions. The reason $[0,\infty)$ is closed is that its complement $(-\infty,0)$ is open. See the definition.